# Java: cómo inicializar una propiedad de una clase

Tags: java, poo

El problema consta de 3 códigos dentro de un paquete. Lo que tiene que hacer es calcular los precios de los productos ingresados. En este caso, al usar POO solo se limita a los que uno ingrese en las clases.

El problema en sí ya lo resolví, funciona bien, pero al ejecutarlo la consola me devuelve los nombres de los productos como nulos y la verdad es que no se me está ocurriendo el porqué.

Detalles a tener en cuenta:

Hay algunos productos denominados con valores booleanos, ya que hay una variable de precios promocionales, los cuales poseen precio y calculo separado, y ya que no hay interacción con el usuario, empleé estas para su corroboración.

Adjunto el código a continuación:

1)_

```
    package preciodeventa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Inventario{
    private List<Producto> listProductos;
    public Inventario() {
        this.listProductos = new ArrayList<>();
}
public void agregarProducto(Producto producto) {
    this.listProductos.add(producto);
}
public void informarPrecios() {
    int totalCompra,totalVenta;
    totalCompra = 0;
    totalVenta = 0;
    
    for(Producto producto:this.listProductos){
        System.out.println("Precio de venta para "+ producto.getNombre() + ": "+ producto.getPrecioVenta());
        totalCompra += producto.getPrecio();
        totalVenta += producto.getPrecioVenta();
    }
    System.out.println("Total precios de compra: "+ totalCompra);
    System.out.println("Total precios de venta: "+ totalVenta);

}
}
```

2)_

```
package preciodeventa;

public class Aplicacion {

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        Producto television = new Producto("television",2500,45,true);
        Producto telefono = new Producto("telefono",2500,50,false);
        Producto tostadora = new Producto("tuesta pan",3000,45,false);
        
        Inventario inventario = new Inventario();
        
        
        inventario.agregarProducto(television);
        inventario.agregarProducto(telefono);
        inventario.agregarProducto(tostadora);
        inventario.informarPrecios();
    }
}
```

3)_

```
  package preciodeventa;

public class Producto {
    private int precio;
    private int stock;
    private String nombre;
    private int precio_final;
    private boolean Espromocional;

    public Producto(String nombre, int precio , int stock ,boolean promocional) {

        this.precio = precio;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.Espromocional = promocional;
        
        double calculo;
        double ganancia;
        
    if (promocional){
        ganancia = precio;
    }
    else {
        if ((stock >=100 && precio >1500)||stock <50) {
                ganancia = precio * 1.15;
        }
        else {
                ganancia = precio * 1.20;
        }

    }   

    calculo = precio + (ganancia * 0.21);
    
    this.precio_final = (int) calculo;
    
}


    public int getPrecio() {
        return precio;
}
    public int getPrecioVenta() {
        return precio_final;
}
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
}
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
}
    public Boolean getPromocional() {
        return Espromocional;
    }
}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema que tienes exactamente??

Comment: Mejora el título de tu pregunta: ¿cuál es el problema en cuestión? Lee [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la clase Producto, en el constructor te falta el

```
this.nombre=nombre;
```